# SQL Server Stored Procedure Update with SUM on INNER JOIN

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am working in SQL Server 2005, creating a stored procedure to pull payor/billing data from my database.

The stored procedure creates a temp table to pass back to the application (VB.NET).  The first part pulls every record from the period balance table into the temp table and then determines the "age" of the balance for that period (current, 30 days past due, 60 days past due, etc.).  This works fine.

What I now need to do is determine the number of days charged for the current period.  So I pull all records from my temp table where the age is 'CUR'.  The number of days is stored in a separate table in my database called charge.  There may be multiple charge records for one period.  In those cases I want the sum of all of the days for that period.

For example, one person for the period of March 1 - March 31 may have 4 separate charge records: first records has 3 days, second record has 6 days, third record has 1 day, fourth record has 5 days.  What I want in my temp table is just ONE record for this person for this period, with the days value at 15.

Currently the procedure is producing the correct number of days for 3 people (out of 102 people).  82 people have NULL for days.  There are a few people where that would be correct, but definitely not 82 of them.  The remaining people seem to have days that increase randomly.  The number of days cannot be more than the number of days in the month but there are people with the days column set to a number in the hundreds and even in the thousands.

This is related to [the question I posted yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929560/sql-server-group-by-sum-by-company-name-balance) but is a different part of the report.

I would appreciate any help you can give.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [AgedPayorReport]    
    @VCurrStart     DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY

        CREATE TABLE #t_temp
            (                    
                bal                     DECIMAL(11, 2), 
                period                  DATETIME,
                account_code            INT,
                payor_code              INT,
                plan_code               INT,        
                age                     VARCHAR(10),
                census_days             INT
            )          

        DECLARE @VCurrEnd           DATETIME
        DECLARE @V30Start           DATETIME
        DECLARE @V60Start           DATETIME
        DECLARE @V90Start           DATETIME
        DECLARE @V120Start          DATETIME
        DECLARE @V150Start          DATETIME
        DECLARE @V180Start          DATETIME
        DECLARE @V210Start          DATETIME
        DECLARE @V240Start          DATETIME

SET @VCurrEnd = DATEADD(DAY,-1,(DATEADD(MONTH,1,@VCurrStart)))
SET @V30Start = DATEADD(month,-1,@VCurrStart)
SET @V60Start = DATEADD(month,-2,@VCurrStart)
SET @V90Start = DATEADD(month,-3,@VCurrStart)
SET @V120Start = DATEADD(month,-4,@VCurrStart)
SET @V150Start = DATEADD(month,-5,@VCurrStart)
SET @V180Start = DATEADD(month,-6,@VCurrStart)
SET @V210Start = DATEADD(month,-7,@VCurrStart)
SET @V240Start = DATEADD(month,-8,@VCurrStart)

INSERT INTO #t_temp
            (                    
                bal,
                period,             
                age
            )            
SELECT    
                b.ledger_bal,
                b.period,               
                (SELECT CASE 
                WHEN period > @VCurrStart THEN 'ADV'
                WHEN period = @VCurrStart THEN 'CUR'
                WHEN period = @V30Start THEN '30'
                WHEN period = @V60Start THEN '60'
                WHEN period = @V90Start THEN '90'
                WHEN period = @V120Start THEN '120'
                WHEN period = @V150Start THEN '150'
                WHEN period = @V180Start THEN '180'
                WHEN period = @V210Start THEN '210'
                WHEN period = @V240Start THEN '240'
                WHEN period < @V240Start THEN '270'
                END)
            FROM balance b WITH(NOLOCK)         


SELECT *
INTO #t_temp_CUR
FROM #t_temp
WHERE age = 'CUR'


UPDATE t
SET t.census_days = (charge.sum_days)
FROM #t_temp_CUR t
INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT account_code, SUM(days) AS sum_days
        FROM charge WITH(NOLOCK)
        GROUP BY account_code
    ) as charge
    ON charge.account_code = t.account_code
INNER JOIN charge c WITH(NOLOCK)
ON c.account_code = t.account_code
AND c.payor_code = t.payor_code
AND c.plan_code = t.plan_code
WHERE c.start_date >= @VCurrStart
AND c.end_date <= @VCurrEnd
AND c.type = 'C'
AND c.void <> 1
AND c.days <> 0
AND c.days IS NOT NULL


END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

    END CATCH
END
```

Edited to add sample data:

Existing period balance table:

```
account_code    payor_code      plan_code       period      ledger_bal  period_bal_code
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
9421            493             224             2012-07-01  191.82      30813
9420            6833            527             2012-07-01  767.28      30810
9419            6533            510             2012-07-01  1400.00     30806
9418            6533            510             2012-07-01  1400.00     30803
9417            493             224             2012-07-01  959.10      30800
9416            2193            340             2012-07-01  244.17      30794
9416            8468            584             2012-07-01  1370.00     30795
9416            8935            433             2012-07-01  250.00      30798
9415            493             224             2012-07-01  1150.92     30791
9414            6158            495             2012-07-01  2916.00     30788
9413            6833            527             2012-07-01  6385.61     30785
9412            6034            474             2012-07-01  8488.16     30781
9412            8930            433             2012-07-01  800.00      30783
9411            493             224             2012-07-01  7840.18     30777
9410            8468            584             2012-07-01  6156.00     30776
```

Some corresponding records in the charge table:

```
account_code    payor_code      plan_code   charge_code start_date  end_date    quantity    gross_amount    net_amount      days    void
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
9413            6833            527         5070631     2012-07-21  2012-07-31  1           2508.00         6385.61         11      0
9411            493             224         5070755     2012-07-16  2012-07-29  1           3192.00         6972.28         14      0
9411            493             224         5070757     2012-07-30  2012-07-31  1           456.00          867.90          2       0
9416            8468            584         5071869     2012-07-27  2012-07-31  1           1140.00         1620.00         5       0
9418            6533            510         5072255     2012-07-28  2012-07-31  1           912.00          1400.00         4       0
9417            493             224         5073818     2012-07-27  2012-07-31  1           1140.00         959.10          5       0
9410            8468            584         5075878     2012-07-12  2012-07-30  1           4332.00         6156.00         19      0
9420            6833            527         5076857     2012-07-28  2012-07-31  1           912.00          767.28          4       0
9412            6034            474         5076991     2012-07-16  2012-07-16  1           228.00          580.51          1       0
9412            6034            474         5076994     2012-07-17  2012-07-29  1           2964.00         7546.63         13      0
9412            6034            474         5076997     2012-07-30  2012-07-31  1           456.00          1161.02         2       0
9421            493             224         5077918     2012-07-31  2012-07-31  1           228.00          191.82          1       0
9414            6158            495         5079045     2012-07-23  2012-07-31  1           2052.00         2916.00         9       0
9419            6533            510         5079366     2012-07-28  2012-07-31  1           912.00          1400.00         4       0
9415            493             224         5079418     2012-07-26  2012-07-31  1           1368.00         1150.92         6       0
9410            8468            584         5084838     2012-07-12  2012-07-30  1           -4332.00        -6156.00        19      0
9410            8468            584         5085112     2012-07-12  2012-07-30  1           4332.00         6156.00         19      0
9413            6833            527         5085371     2012-08-01  2012-08-03  1           684.00          1741.53         3       0
9413            6833            527         5085373     2012-08-04  2012-08-09  1           1368.00         1150.92         6       0
9413            6833            527         5085375     2012-08-10  2012-08-31  1           5016.00         4220.04         22      0
```

So take account # 9411.  Current stored procedure produces:

```
ledger_bal  period      account_code    payor_code      plan_code       age     census_days
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
7840.18     2012-07-01  9411            493             224             CUR         70
```

But I want it to produce:

```
ledger_bal  period      account_code    payor_code      plan_code       age     census_days
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
7840.18     2012-07-01  9411            493             224             CUR         16
```

Comment: Could you show a small subset of sample data and desired results from that sample data? Even if I didn't fall asleep during the word problem, I'd have no way to know if my corrections to your query yield the correct results.

Comment: Do any of these charges in the charge table overlap period boundaries? If so, this is going to be more difficult.  Also, in your sample Charge table data, account_code 9410 looks like there was a charge an a refund, or something like that, because you have in the amount columns a number and an identical (but negative) number.  Presumably the 19 days of one of them is really a negative 19 days to offset the positive 19 days.  I presume you want 0 days for 9410, rather than 19 or 38 days?

Comment: No, charges are strictly separated by period.  No overlap.  For account 9410, the days should sum up once for each start/end date period.  So account 9410 has three records in the charge table but all start on 7/12 and end on 7/30, so all charges are for the same period.  Account 9410 should have a total of 19 days.

Comment: I've tried to work with this but the stored procedure doesn't parse. First, `balance` doesn't have a column called `bal` - did you mean `ledger_bal`? Next, I don't know how `#t_temp_CUR` magically got a column called `census_days` - did you miss that in the definition of `#t_temp`? This table also doesn't seem to have other columns you reference, such as `account_code, payor_code and plan_code`.

Comment: My apologies, I accidentally copied the temp table definition from an earlier draft.  I have fixed it.  The balance column is ledger_bal, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

I created another table called #t_days containing only the fields needed to link to the charge table, plus the days.  I still select the current #t_temp records into #t_temp_CUR, and then I link ***that*** to my charge table to insert the individual charge records in #t_days.  I then run an update statement and pull the SUM of the census_days from #t_days.  This is now producing the correct number of days for each record.

Thanks!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [AgedPayorReport]    
    @VCurrStart     DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY

        CREATE TABLE #t_temp
            (                    
                bal                     DECIMAL(11, 2), 
                period                  DATETIME,
                account_code            INT,
                payor_code              INT,
                plan_code               INT,        
                age                     VARCHAR(10),
                census_days             INT
            )

    CREATE TABLE #t_days
            (               
                account_code            INT,
                payor_code              INT,
                plan_code               INT,                
                census_days             INT             
            )

        DECLARE @VCurrEnd           DATETIME
        DECLARE @V30Start           DATETIME
        DECLARE @V60Start           DATETIME
        DECLARE @V90Start           DATETIME
        DECLARE @V120Start          DATETIME
        DECLARE @V150Start          DATETIME
        DECLARE @V180Start          DATETIME
        DECLARE @V210Start          DATETIME
        DECLARE @V240Start          DATETIME

SET @VCurrEnd = DATEADD(DAY,-1,(DATEADD(MONTH,1,@VCurrStart)))
SET @V30Start = DATEADD(month,-1,@VCurrStart)
SET @V60Start = DATEADD(month,-2,@VCurrStart)
SET @V90Start = DATEADD(month,-3,@VCurrStart)
SET @V120Start = DATEADD(month,-4,@VCurrStart)
SET @V150Start = DATEADD(month,-5,@VCurrStart)
SET @V180Start = DATEADD(month,-6,@VCurrStart)
SET @V210Start = DATEADD(month,-7,@VCurrStart)
SET @V240Start = DATEADD(month,-8,@VCurrStart)

INSERT INTO #t_temp
            (                    
                bal,
                period,             
                account_code,
                payor_code,
                plan_code,
                age
            )            
SELECT    
                b.ledger_bal,
                b.period, 
                b.account_code,
                b.payor_code,
                b.plan_code,
                (SELECT CASE 
                WHEN period > @VCurrStart THEN 'ADV'
                WHEN period = @VCurrStart THEN 'CUR'
                WHEN period = @V30Start THEN '30'
                WHEN period = @V60Start THEN '60'
                WHEN period = @V90Start THEN '90'
                WHEN period = @V120Start THEN '120'
                WHEN period = @V150Start THEN '150'
                WHEN period = @V180Start THEN '180'
                WHEN period = @V210Start THEN '210'
                WHEN period = @V240Start THEN '240'
                WHEN period < @V240Start THEN '270'
                END)
            FROM balance b WITH(NOLOCK)         


SELECT *
INTO #t_temp_CUR
FROM #t_temp
WHERE age = 'CUR'


INSERT INTO #t_days
            (               
                account_code,
                payor_code,             
                plan_code,
                census_days
            )
SELECT 
t.account_code, 
t.payor_code, 
t.plan_code,
c.days
FROM #t_temp_CUR t
INNER JOIN br549.charge c WITH(NOLOCK)
ON t.account_code = c.account_code
AND t.payor_code = c.payor_code
AND t.plan_code = c.plan_code
WHERE c.type = 'C'
AND c.advance = ''
AND c.void <> 1
AND c.start_date >= @vkVCurrStart
AND c.end_date <= @vkVCurrEnd


UPDATE #t_temp
SET census_days = 
(SELECT SUM(census_days)
FROM #t_days
WHERE #t_days.account_code = #t_temp.account_code
AND #t_days.payor_code = #t_temp.payor_code
AND #t_days.plan_code = #t_temp.plan_code
AND #t_days.period = #t_temp.period)

SELECT * FROM #t_temp


END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

    END CATCH
END
```